# React Native switch component's state resets after re-entering screen

Tags: react-native, expo, tsx

I'm using React Native's switch component to toggle between Light and Dark modes, using States, Context and Event Listeners and the switch's state is resetting after re-entering the screen where it is at with a weird behavior I haven't seen anywhere online.

This is the file where the switch is at:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, Switch } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import theme from '../assets/styles/theme';
import ThemeContext from '../context/ThemeContext';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { EventRegister } from 'react-native-event-listeners';

const Settings = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const colors: any = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const [mode, setMode] = useState(false);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView
            style={[theme.container, { backgroundColor: colors.background }]}
        >
            <Switch
                onValueChange={(value) => {
                    setMode((value) => !value);
                    EventRegister.emit('changeTheme', value);
                }}
                value={mode}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
                style={[theme.button, { backgroundColor: colors.button }]}
            >
                <Text style={[theme.buttonText, { color: colors.buttonText }]}>
                    Back
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <StatusBar style={mode === false ? 'dark' : 'light'}></StatusBar>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default Settings;
```

And this App.tsx where the Event Listener is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import { EventRegister } from 'react-native-event-listeners';
import ThemeContext from './context/ThemeContext';
import colors from './assets/colors/colors';

export default function App() {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        let eventListener: string = EventRegister.addEventListener(
            'changeTheme',
            (data) => {
                setMode(data);
            }
        );
        return () => {
            EventRegister.removeEventListener(eventListener);
        };
    });

    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={mode === true ? colors.dark : colors.light}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <AppNavigator />
            </NavigationContainer>
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

[And this is the weird behavior:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwXxy.gif)

I am still pretty new and learning React so any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

After the suggestion from [user18309290](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18309290/user18309290) I managed to do a workaround that works.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, Switch } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import theme from '../assets/styles/theme';
import ThemeContext from '../context/ThemeContext';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { EventRegister } from 'react-native-event-listeners';
import colors from '../assets/colors/colors';

const Settings = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const scheme: any = useContext(ThemeContext);
    let aux = scheme;
    aux === colors.dark ? (aux = true) : (aux = false);
    const [mode, setMode] = useState(aux);
    return (
        <SafeAreaView
            style={[theme.container, { backgroundColor: scheme.background }]}
        >
            <Switch
                onValueChange={(value) => {
                    setMode((value) => !value);
                    EventRegister.emit('changeTheme', value);
                }}
                value={aux}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
                style={[theme.button, { backgroundColor: scheme.button }]}
            >
                <Text style={[theme.buttonText, { color: scheme.buttonText }]}>
                    Back
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <StatusBar style={mode === false ? 'dark' : 'light'}></StatusBar>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default Settings;
```

While I'm not exactly happy with it and will probably rework it later, it does solve the issue and the switch now works properly, in case someone has the same problem I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState` just adds a state variable to a component like `Settings`. When a component mounts a variable is set to default like `false`.

Use `context` to set the default value. Something like this:

```
const colors: any = useContext(ThemeContext);
const [mode, setMode] = useState(colors.mode);
```

Or remove the local state all together.

Comment: While I couldn't do that exactly that, because 'colors' has the values of the colors of the current theme and as such 'colors.mode' just became undefined, I managed to do a "sketchy" workaround that seems to work. I'll edit the question to include it. Thanks for the help!